# c++: I am getting a wierd value in my array

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I have a assignment to create a Arraylist( from 1d arrays) in c++, and I have each method functioning, but i am getting a weird value in my array that I am not adding in. Basically what happens is when I add to my array if the number of items in my array become equal to the length of the array I double the size of the array. Well when my array length gets to length=8, in the arr[6] there is a value of 33. Is this a memory issue? this place should be 0.

here is my cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include "ArrayList.h"

using namespace std;
void ArrayList:: intialArr(int arr[])
{
    cout << "intialArr ran" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
}

std::string ArrayList:: toString()
{
    cout << "{ ";
 for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
 {
    cout << "arr[" << i << "] = " << arr[i] << " ";
 }
 cout << " }";
}

ArrayList::ArrayList()
{
    length = 1;
    capacity=0;
    arr = new int[length];
    cout << "length = " << length << " " << "capacity = " << capacity << endl;
    intialArr(arr);
    cout << "ArrayList created"<<endl;
}

int& ArrayList:: operator[] (unsigned int i)
{
    cout << "operator[] is working" << endl;
    int *p = &arr[i];
    return *p;

}

void ArrayList:: push_back(int m)
{
    if(capacity>=length)
    {   
        length = length*2;
        cout << "length = " << length << endl;
        int* curArr = new int[length];
        intialArr(curArr);
        for (int i = 0; i<length; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i])
            {
                cout << "arr[" << i << "] in pushback method(if) is: " <<               arr[i]<< endl;
                curArr[i] = arr[i];
            }
            else
            {
            cout << "arr[" << i << "] in pushback method(else) is: " << arr[i]              << endl;
                curArr[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        delete [] arr;
        arr = curArr;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {

            if(arr[i]==0)
            {
            arr[i] = m;
            capacity++;
            cout << "arr at " << i << " is: " << arr[i];
            cout << " and should be: " << m << endl;
            cout << "capacity is: " << capacity << endl;
            break;
            }
    }   
}

void ArrayList:: erase(int m)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==m)
        {
            for(int j = i; j<length; j++)
            {
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                cout<< "arr[" << j << "] is: " << arr[j] << " and should be: ";
                cout << arr[j+1] << endl;
            }
                capacity--;
                cout << "capacity is: " << capacity << endl;
        }
    }
    if((length/capacity) == 2)
        {   
        length = length/2;
        cout << "length = " << length << endl;
        int* curArr = new int[length];
        intialArr(curArr);
        for (int i = 0; i<length; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i])
            {
                cout << "arr[" << i << "] in pushback method(if) is: " <<               arr[i]<< endl;
                curArr[i] = arr[i];
            }
            else
            {
            cout << "arr[" << i << "] in pushback method(else) is: " << arr[i]              << endl;
                curArr[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        delete [] arr;
        arr = curArr;
    }
}


int main()
{
    ArrayList arr;
    arr.push_back(1);
    arr.push_back(1);
    arr.push_back(1);
    arr.push_back(1);
    arr.push_back(1);
    arr.push_back(1);

}
```

and here is the results of my array:

```
arr[0] in pushback method(if) is: 1
arr[1] in pushback method(if) is: 1
arr[2] in pushback method(if) is: 1
arr[3] in pushback method(if) is: 1
arr[4] in pushback method(if) is: 1
arr[5] in pushback method(if) is: 1
arr[6] in pushback method(if) is: 33
arr[7] in pushback method(else) is: 0
```

and no vectors are allowed and when I try to hardcode arr[6]=0 I get a very odd error.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What if capacity is less then length in push_back

Comment: buffer overflow should be if(i <  length/2   && arr[i]) in push back

Comment: @drescherjm: It seems that the variable named `length` has the capacity, and vice versa.

Comment: capacity is = to the number of elements in the array, while length is = to the number of elements the array can hold.

Comment: I could see that from the code. ... And it is the opposite of how every other library uses those names in association with containers.

Answer (score 2):

The following block of code in `push_back()` is cause for undefined behavior since you are accessing `arr` out of bounds.

```
    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i])
        {
            cout << "arr[" << i << "] in pushback method(if) is: " <<               arr[i]<< endl;
            curArr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        else
        {
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] in pushback method(else) is: " << arr[i]              << endl;
            curArr[i] = 0;
        }
```

You need to save the old length, copy the data from `arr` to `curArr` using the old length, and proceed to add the input argument to the new array.

Also, the check:

```
if(arr[i]==0)
```

will be OK as long as you don't push a `0` to your array.

I would revise `push_back` as:

```
void ArrayList:: push_back(int m)
{
    if(capacity>=length)
    {   
       int oldLength = length;

       length = length*2;
       cout << "length = " << length << endl;
       int* curArr = new int[length];
       intialArr(curArr);
       for (int i = 0; i < oldLength; i++)
       {
          curArr[i] = arr[i];
       }
       delete [] arr;
       arr = curArr;
    }

    arr[capacity] = m;
    capacity++;
}
```

Comment: Or actually it's the names "length" and "capacity" that are backwards

Comment: @BenVoigt, those names are backward but I think that's not the cause of his problem.